# colpick doesn't work on .html to .php extension change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im using this Color Picker Jquery plugin (http://colpick.com/plugin)

Problem is, i tried same simple code in in .html but when i change just extension to .php, the Color Picker doesnt work, while everything else works.

A simple button and added the important scripts like colpick.js and colpick.css.

Example:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="canvasSettings.js"></script>
    <script src="colpick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colpick.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <button id="idColor">Show Color Picker</button>
</body>
</html>
```

canvasSettings.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

alert("First");

$('#idColor').colpick();

alert("Second");

});
```

So in index.html, when you click on button, it opens the Color Picker and both alert's show up, all good here.

Problem is, when i change index.html to index.php (when using an php server), the site loads up normaly, button shows up and "First" alert shows up.
But when it reaches the $("#idColor").colpick({}) it doesnt process, "Second" alert doesn't show up.
Have in mind that $("idColor").val() works.

Is there any special way to change this .html into .php even tho the html code is the same?

Comment: watch paths to the files

Comment: consult the console for errors

Comment: When you inspect the page, is the colpick.js script loaded? `$("idColor").val()` works because it is not part of the colpick.js library but the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. It has nothing to do with serving up the HTML from PHP instead of a static file.

Here you load jQuery:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Then you load the plugin which *binds itself to jQuery*:

```
<script src="colpick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you load jQuery *again* (but a different version):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This **overwrites** the previous jQuery object and the colour picker plugin that you had bound to it.

---

1. Decide which version of jQuery you are going to use (the faster 2.x or 1.x with support for old versions of IE).
2. Load it **before** you load the plug in (you are currently doing that for 2.x but not 1.x)
3. Don't load the other version

Comment: Thanks, very simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
The problem was caused by:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

after i removed that, it worked.
Still need to find a bypass around that, why it caused the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to include jQuery twice? you already have `<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Good point, my colleague added those and i thought it was some other version (being new with jquery).